# Docker on creating .net core 3.1 Linux Image, Getting SSL certificate Error, The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedur

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, docker-registry

I have created one ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web API project having reference of .net standard library 2.0

My development machine is window and when I trying to create a docker image for Linux environment (`docker build -t aspdotnetdemo`) I am getting the error below:

> Unable to load the service index for source
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.405/NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   The SSL
> connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.405/NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   The
> remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: which is your base image?

Comment: Change your base image 
"mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim" to "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal" mention if that does not help

Comment: From the error message, it seems that the certificate is invalid, try to check whether it is trusted or not. Besides, you could try to clean the certificate first, then re-add it. Here are some related articles, you can refer them:[Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [How to set up a developer certificate for Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#how-to-set-up-a-developer-certificate-for-docker).